# Google Federated OAuth/OpenID with Tornado: why is it ignoring my scopes?

Tags: oauth, tornado, google-data-api, google-openid, google-data

I'm trying to use Tornado's library for federated login to authenticate users and get access to their calendar, contacts, and mail.  However, when I get the "mydomain.dyndns.info is asking for some information from your Google Account" message, the only bullet point listed is "Email Address".  Subsequently, when I check the returned user object after I approve the request, the user object doesn't have an 'access_token' property.

Here's the code:

```
def get(self):
    scope_list = ['https://mail.google.com/','http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/','http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/']
    ...
    self.authorize_redirect(scope_list, callback_uri=self._switch_command('auth_callback'), ax_attrs=["name","email"])
def _on_auth(self, user):
    print 'in on auth'
    if user:
        self.set_the_user(user['email'])
        session.set_data('usertoken_' + user['email'], user['access_token'])
    self.redirect('/')
```

The uri that this spits out is:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.dyndns.info%3A333%2Fauth%2Fauth_callback%3Fperms%3Dgmail%26perms%3Dcontacts%26perms%3Dcalendar
&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.dyndns.info%3A333%2F
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns.oauth=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Foauth%2F1.0
&openid.oauth.consumer=mydomain.dyndns.info
&openid.oauth.scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2F+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Ffeeds%2F
&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0
&openid.ax.type.fullname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson
&openid.ax.type.lastname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast
&openid.ax.type.firstname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst
&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request
&openid.ax.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail
&openid.ax.required=firstname%2Cfullname%2Clastname%2Cemail
```

Ideas: 1. maybe this has something to do with the fact I'm running on a local machine behind a dyndns forwarder? 2. Tornado's documentation says "No application registration is necessary to use Google for authentication or to access Google resources on behalf of a user" -- but maybe that's not true anymore?

If anyone has thoughts, I'd really appreciate it -- this is driving me a little batty!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  You have to set the application properties google_consumer_key and google_consumer_secret.

```
application = tornado.web.Application(urlhandlers, cookie_secret=cookie_secret, google_consumer_key=google_consumer_key, google_consumer_secret=google_consumer_secret)
```

You get them by going here: https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains